# Where are the implemented libraries stored in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

For example, I have this in my build.gradle:

implementation 'com.github.mmoamenn:LuckyWheel_Android:0.3.0'

Where are the classes stored if I want to change something in the library?

Thanks!

Comment: Given that artifact name, presumably there is a GitHub repo for it.

Comment: Yeah, but after they get pulled from github, I wondered where are they stored. I know it's not good practice, but I wanted to try to change something quick just to see if it works.

Comment: Well... for that, you need source code. That *may* be included in the downloaded materials, but it may not. The details of where Gradle stores downloaded artifacts depends on your OS -- on Linux and macOS, you will find all of Gradle's files in `~/.gradle`.

Comment: And just changing the source code won't be enough: you need to compile them and make _your changed version_ the dependency instead of the original. Maybe as a source dependency https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select "Project" on your Project Dropdown
[image]

And then you'll be able to see your `External Libraries`